# If $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^n$, does $\sum_{k=1}^{n}v_k^2$ has any specific name?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ with $v_k$ as its $k^{\text{th}}$ entry. We know that $\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert^2=\underset{k=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}|v_k|^2$ is the square of the $L^2$ norm of $\mathbf{v}$. I wonder, does $\underset{k=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}v_k^2\in\mathbb{C}$ has any specific name?

Comment: The sum of the squares of the entries/components?  If this doesn't satisfy you, maybe you can call it "Edward"?

Comment: You could call it the quadratic form associated to the identity matrix.

Comment: this term has appeared in my studies and now to look for it online, I want to see if it has any name.

Comment: Sometimes it is called the energy of the vector.